# Is there a way to read OSX .numbers files?

Tags: libreoffice, conversion

A friend has given me a spreadsheet generated by Mac OSX "Numbers" and before I ask her to resend it, I'm wondering if there's secretly a way that I can just read this in Ubuntu.

Is there maybe a plugin for LibreOffice? Just googling isn't turning up much -- "numbers" kind of gets lost in the noise.

Comment: [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/numbers-to-xls/) usually works OK...  but that can be annoying, takes ages, etc. LibreOffice has [quite a few extensions](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center), but sadly this does not appear to be amongst them. Even if it did have the right extension, it would be a matter of whether it would work or not...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and the file with ".numbers" extension opens correctly with LibreOffice Calc

Comment: I found myself once again needing to open a `.numbers` on Ubuntu and this time it just worked to open it from within Calc.

Comment: Although the macros are all gone (not surprised)...

Answer (score 10):

Steps:

1. Log into [icloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/#numbers) and click on "Numbers"
2. Upload the .Numbers file to your iCloud account. Some browsers support drag-and-drop
3. Download the file in .CSV or .XLSX format. Download options are available by alt-clicking the file you just uploaded
4. Open in LibreOffice

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather comment but not enough points... 
I think I would ask your friend to use numbers to do the following and send you a .csv file.
Any of us with numbers could do it for you. I will if you wish to send me the file... I have MS Office on my Mac and  several other office packages. On my ubuntu box I have libreoffice, if I can help you... 
scott

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5491619

Comment: She's not super tech savvy and the point of sending me this file was that she could stop dealing with it and it would be my problem. So before I ask her to go open it and save as csv, I want to figure out if I can do the legwork myself.

Comment: @ScottPorter, it is probably possible to export to xml or xls formats, which can then be imported into LibreOffice at the click of a button...

Comment: Your link does not work by the way...

Comment: I just tried the link, apple says:back soon, sorry Amanda. As for xml or xls, I tried in numbers v 3.0.1 and PDf, Excel and CSV are the export options.  Sorry I wasn't more help.

Comment: Link is fixed, FWIW.

Comment: Accepting b/c it is pretty clear that re-saving in a format I can read is the only real option.

Comment: do you want me to try Amanda/ or your friend? If so I can give you my email.

Comment: Changing the accepted answer because sometime in the last six years, Calc has learned to read `.numbers` files. Whew!

Answer (score 0):

This online tool can be used -> https://www.zamzar.com/convert/numbers-to-csv/

Comment: would not be optimal for big files